When should I use "the" and when don't I need to use it?
I am writing a paper with the following sentence

The coherent information associated with the code subspace C and the noise channel N is another measure of recoverable quantum information after N.

However, my collaborator told me that I should not use "the" in front of "code subspace" and “noise channel". I am confused and can anyone tell me when I should or shouldn't use "the" in a sentence?

It's your choice, but I'd leave them out.

... Yes; if there is more than one subspace C and more than one noise channel N, the definite article is misleading. In fact,  'a' and 'the associated' are best. But if C and N are uniquely specified (there's only one code subspace C, though subspaces D, E ... exist also), the definite articles are optional (but be consistent). If C and N are unique (no D ... or O, P ...), the definite articles are again optional. // It would be best to clarify the actual situation.

Welcome to SE EL&U. Please finish the [Tour] and note that we have a sister site English Language learners, where basic questions on the use of articles in English belong.

Most readers of such formal, technical prose would expect “the code subspace C ” to imply that there exists exactly one code subspace under discussion and that its name is C. By contrast, without the definite article, the noun phrase would most easily be understood as referring to one of several code subspaces, the one named C. To make it more clear that one means the former, one can insert a comma after subspace.
The same goes for “noise channel N.”

Do you mean "insert a comma after subspace"? I'd also say that without the definite article, I would read "...associated with code subspace C..." not as referring to a subspace named C (i.e. the writer chose a subspace and has already given it the name C), but as referring to the reader's favorite subspace and creating a new name C for it that can be used from now on. But this convention could easily vary by field, so take this with a grain of salt!

Thanks, @DanielWagner, for catching my mistake. I’ve fixed it.

The isolated sentence seems to work as well without both instances of the, in which case I would take them out. But crossing stuff out may only take you to a local best solution. Sometimes you have to start afresh. How about...

For a code subspace C and a noise channel N, the coherent information associated with C and N is another measure of the recoverable quantum information after N.

Are C and N used before this sentence? If it is another measure, you don't want to contradict what has gone before. But for me looking at the sentence in isolation, putting the definitions of C and N at the front seems to get over the awkwardness. Choose your C and N, rather than using articles to hint whether they are specific or general.
